# Custom NSDrawer

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nswindow, drawer

I tried to make a Custom `NSDrawer` by changing it's `NSWindow` but subclassing `NSDrawer` didn't help. I was wondering is it possible to make `NSDrawer` looks completely customized. If it is, what is the best approach?

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by '*subclassing it's NSWindow*' - the `NSDrawer` class isn't a subclass of `NSWindow`, it's a class on it's own right ([AppKit class hierarchy](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/ObjC_classic/Intro/IntroAppKit.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000689-21025)) [Sounds like](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4868652/subclassing-an-nsdrawers-contentview-to-implement-a-completely-custom-drawer) you can't currently change the window class of `NSDrawer` to something that doesn't draw the usual adornments so as of now (10.8) we'

Comment: I said changing NSWindow of NSDrawer by subclassing NSDrawer, I didn't say NSDrawer is a subclass of NSWindow.

Comment: I couldn't change NSDrawer alphaValue and even it's border. I think only access we have is it's content view. Simulating a NSDrawer requires a bit of work that I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: Yeah.. tough one. Sounds like all (public accessible) means to customize `NSDrawer` is via the content view, no way to change the window to a custom class that's transparent as it appears to use a [private NSWindow subclass](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4868652/subclassing-an-nsdrawers-contentview-to-implement-a-completely-custom-drawer)..